# Create a shell script that returns the last 5 hash of my commits of my git deposit

Tags: bash, git, shell, github

I need to write a shell script that returns the last 5 hashes of my commits in my git deposit.

I'm gonna show you an example below

```
%> bash git_commit.sh | cat -e
baa23b54f0adb7bf42623d6d0a6ed4587e11412$$
2f52d74b1387fa80eea844969e8dc5483b531ac1$
905f53d98656771334f53f59bb984fc29774701f$
5ddc8474f4f15b3fcb72d08fcb333e19c3a27078$
e94d0b448c03ec633f16d84d63beaef9ae7e7be8$
%>
```

Answer (score 8):

This should do it:

```
% git log --format='%H' -n5
4f4716883559a9e8e17e37a02ec4face77b1b5f3
08b3f398e2c63a83d02e0279ffa3f156c2631828
5e38051582e898d317a4906e4ff85377d71764bd
424ab5eaf924d2d4ead36c91847ef3df18f7fa64
f402ef630d9ee5755ceb9059d9627b3e9fb64d63
```

Here is a complete shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
git log --format='%H' -n5
```

Comment: How can I write this on a shell script ?

Comment: You have a local clone, yes? `cd` there, `git pull` the latest, and then just execute GaryO's `git log --format='%H' -n5`, possibly redirecting into a file or loading into an array. What do you need to *do* with it? That might matter...

Comment: Just copy that line I gave you into a file `git-commits.sh` and make it executable (`chmod +x git-commits.sh`). Best to start the script with a shell line: `#! /bin/sh`, then the line I gave you.

Comment: @PaulHodges This is an exercise for school, and I have no idea how shell works, they're asking from me to write a shell script that they'll execute using bash git_commit.sh | cat -e in the terminal, but I have no idea what I should be writing inside of my shell script

Comment: Or just `git rev-list -5 @`

Comment: @AyoubABOUNAKIF I added the complete script above. Just save that to `git_commit.sh`, then your teacher's command `bash git_commit.sh | cat -e` will work.